# How can i make the img take 100% of the page no matter how big or small the screen is

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, frontend

you can try by going to a lower reseslution the img will drop down.
i bought this landing page but when i try a diffrent resolution image  it don't act the same as the original image that came with the file, i also modify some section and remove some i hope i didn't make a mistake by removing something.

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 100);
});

let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navlist = document.querySelector('.navlist');

menu.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navlist.classList.toggle('open');
};

window.onscroll = () => {
    menu.classList.remove('bx-x');
    navlist.classList.remove('open');
};
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.img-cover {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
/* Custom default button */
.btn-light,
.btn-light:hover,
.btn-light:focus {
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */

body {
    text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.cover-container {
    max-width: 42em;
}

/*
 * Header
 */

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0.25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
:root {
    --bg-color: #2a2a2a;
    --second-bg-color: #202020;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --second-color: #ccc;
    --main-color: #537fe7;
    --big-font: 3rem;
    --h2-font: 3.5rem;
    --p-font: 1.1rem;
}
body {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 22px 12%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.logo {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
span {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.navlist {
    display: flex;
}
.navlist a {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0 25px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.navlist a:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.navlist a.active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
#menu-icon {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    z-index: 10001;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: none;
}

section {
    padding: 160px 12% 120px;
}
.home {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.slide {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.one {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
.two {
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.home-text h1 {
    font-size: var(--big-font);
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--text-color);
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
}
.home-text h3 {
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
.home-text p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.button {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 28px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.btn2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin-left: 35px;
}
.btn2 span i {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.btn2 span i:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(5px);
}

header.sticky {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff1a;
    padding: 12px 12%;
}

.about {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}
.about-img img {
    max-width: 530px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.about-text h2 {
    font-size: var(--h2-font);
    margin: 0px 0 30px;
    line-height: 1;
}
.about-text h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text-color);
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin: 15px 0 30px;
}
.about-text p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.services {
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
}
.main-text {
    text-align: center;
}
.main-text p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.main-text h2 {
    font-size: var(--h2-font);
    line-height: 1;
}
.service-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, auto));
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
.box {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    padding: 35px 45px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.s-icons i {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.box p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.read {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    background: #333333;
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.read:hover {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #ffffff99;
    color: var(--text-color);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, auto));
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
.row {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.row img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.layer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), #537fe7);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}
.layer h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.layer p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
.layer i {
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: var(--text-color);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.row:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.row:hover .layer {
    height: 100%;
}

.contact {
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2.5rem;
}
.contact-text h4 {
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: 18px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.contact-text h2 {
    font-size: var(--h2-font);
    line-height: 1;
}
.contact-text p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list {
    margin-bottom: 2.8rem;
}
.list li {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.list li a {
    display: block;
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.list li a:hover {
    color: var(--text-color);
    transform: translateX(5px);
}
.contact-icons i {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.contact-icons i:hover {
    background: var(--text-color);
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.contact-form form {
    position: relative;
}
.contact-form form input,
form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact-form textarea {
    resize: none;
    height: 240px;
}
.contact-form .submit {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    width: 160px;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
.contact-form .submit:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.end {
    padding: 15px 15%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 2rem;
    background: var(--bg-color);
}
.last-text p {
    color: var(--second-color);
    font-size: 14px;
}
.back-to-top i {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    background: var(--main-color);
}

@media (max-width: 1480px) {
    header {
        padding: 12px 2.5%;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }
    header.sticky {
        padding: 10px 2.5%;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }
    section {
        padding: 80px 3% 60px;
    }
    .end {
        padding: 10px 3%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    :root {
        --big-font: 1.5rem;
        --h2-font: 2.5rem;
        --p-font: 1rem;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }
    .home-text h3 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    .home {
        height: 87vh;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
    .about {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .about-img {
        text-align: center;
        order: 2;
    }
    .about-img img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .contact {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 840px) {
    #menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }
    .navlist {
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        text-align: left;
        transition: all 0.45s ease;
    }
    .navlist a {
        display: block;
        margin: 17px;
        font-size: 20px;
        transition: all 0.45s ease;
        color: var(--text-color);
    }
    .navlist a:hover {
        color: var(--main-color);
    }
    .navlist a.active {
        color: var(--text-color);
    }
    .navlist.open {
        top: 100%;
    }
}
.me {
    padding-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>ELYA MAROC</title>
        <!---custom css link---->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-xn1nJmLwOfDwYI2Nn8bWcZ9XKf86aTqT3rM/AIOcKx2yLmJNNXd/YtRmHfZ+j9eZsD1fbfozvO8WkLL+OInFw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- --header design--->
        <header class="navsm">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><span>ELYA</span> ORIENTAL</a>

            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a href="#home" class="active">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">À propos de nous</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Nos Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contacter Nous</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
        </header>

        <!----home section design--->
        <section class="home" id="home">
            <!-- <div class="home-text">
                <div class="slide">
                    <span class="one">Hello</span>
                    <span class="two">I'm</span>
                </div>
                <h1><span>Societe De Travaux Divers</span></h1>
                <h3>Inox - Aluminium - Verre Trempé</h3>

                <div class="button">
                    <a
                        href="https://wa.me/+212672164343?text=Bonjour"
                        class="btn"
                        target="_blank"
                        ><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i> Contacter Nous</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="btn2"
                        ><span><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></span
                    ></a>
                </div> -->
            <!-- </div> -->
        </section>

        <!-- --about section design- -->
        <section class="about" id="about">
            <div class="about-img">
                <img src="img/about.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="about-text">
                <h2>À propos de <span>nous</span></h2>
                <!-- <h4>TEST TEST TEST</h4> -->
                <p>
                    Elya Oriental propose une large gamme de produits pour répondre à vos
                    besoins en matière de menuiserie aluminium et inox, pose de douches en
                    verre, de cuisines personnalisées, de vente de pièces et
                    d'accessoires, ainsi que tous les types de travaux liés à votre
                    maison.<br />
                    Dirigée par le jeune et ambitieux M. Yabba Abdelmounaim, natif de
                    Saidia, l'entreprise est soutenue par une équipe de professionnels
                    créatifs et compétents. <br />
                    Elya Oriental s'engage à fournir des produits de qualité, dans de
                    meilleurs délais, avec une perfection inégalée.<br />
                    Fondée en 2007, l'entreprise dispose d'un historique de projets
                    réussis et tournée vers l'avenir, avec une grande attention portée aux
                    dernières tendances du marché. Venez nous rendre visite chez Elya
                    Oriental!
                </p>
                <a
                    href="https://wa.me/+212672164343?text=Bonjour"
                    class="btn"
                    target="_blank"
                    ><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i> Contacter Nous</a
                >
                <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></a>
                <!-- <a href="#" class="btn">CONTACTER NOUS</a> -->
            </div>
        </section>

        <!----services section design--->
        <section class="services" id="services">
            <div class="main-text">
                <!-- <p>lorem lorem lorem</p> -->
                <h2><span>Nos</span> Services</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="service-content">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="s-icons"></div>
                    <h3><i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i> Serv 1</h3>
                    <p>
                        <a < href="https://wa.me/+212672164343?text=Bonjour" target="_blank"
                            ><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i> 06 72 16 43 43
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a target="_blank" href="mailto:Elayoriental@hotmail.com"
                            ><i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i>
                            Elayoriental@hotmail.com</a
                        >
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/22oDQFVuf5TdGgxk8" target="_blank"
                            ><i class="fa-solid fa-map-pin"></i> Trifa 2 Saidia</a
                        >
                    </p>
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="read">Read More</a> -->
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="s-icons"></div>
                    <h3><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i> Serv 2</h3>
                    <p>
                        Du lundi au samedi : de 9h00 18h00<br />
                        Venderi de 9h00 a 13h00/ 13h00 a 18h00 <br />
                        Fermé le dimanche.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="read">Read More</a>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="s-icons"></div>
                    <h3><i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i> Serv 3</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <a href="#" class="read">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!----portfolio section design--->
        <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
            <div class="main-text">
                <p>test test test</p>
                <h2>Nos Dernier <span>Projects </span></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio1.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio2.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio3.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio4.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio5.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/portfolio6.jpg" />
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h5>LOREM LOREM</h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
                            veritatis aliquam fuga beatae veniam esse.
                        </p>
                        <!-- <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-link-external"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- --contact section design- -->
        <!-- <section class="contact" id="contact">
            <div class="contact-text">
                <h2>Contacter <span>Nous!</span></h2>
                <h4>test test test test test test.</h4> -->
        <!-- <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam
                    error mollitia accusamus a, porro asperiores placeat minima eaque
                    assumenda reiciendis ipsa voluptate iusto quae maxime ex. Libero harum
                    alias consectetur.
                </p> -->
        <!-- <div class="list">
                    <li><a href="#">0600422374</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test@contact.com</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">adresse adresse</a></li>
                </div> -->

        <!-- <div class="contact-icons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-instagram-alt"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div> -->

        <!-- <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="name" placeholder="Ton nom" required />
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Votre email (optionnel)" required />
                    <input type="" placeholder="Ton numero de telephone" required />
                    <textarea
                        name=""
                        id=""
                        cols="35"
                        rows="10"
                        placeholder="Message"
                        required
                    ></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="submit" required />
                </form>
            </div>
        </section> -->
        <section class="contact" id="contact">
            <div class="contact-text">
                <h2>Contacter <span>Nous!</span></h2>
                <h4>test test test test test test.</h4>
                <!-- <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam
            error mollitia accusamus a, porro asperiores placeat minima eaque
            assumenda reiciendis ipsa voluptate iusto quae maxime ex. Libero harum
            alias consectetur.
        </p> -->
                <div class="list">
                    <li><a href="#">0600422374</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test@contact.com</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">adresse adresse</a></li>
                </div>

                <div class="contact-icons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-instagram-alt"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bx bxl-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!----end section design--->
        <section class="end">
            <div class="last-text">
                <p>Copyright © 2023 par Mohammed Fachouch Tous droits réservés.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="back-to-top">
                <a href="#home"><i class="bx bx-up-arrow-alt"></i></a>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!---custom css link---->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want the cover img to be 100% like this cover on bootstrap [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/cover/)

Comment: do you need all that CSS to place an image full screen? Reduce the problem CSS/HTML to the bare minimum. Do we need JS for this?

Comment: i don't know i bought this landing page for my company, and it comes like this, i don't know if the problem is from the image i should change or i removed something by mistake from the code.

Comment: the only HTML you need is `<div class="img-cover"></div>`, create a small HTML file and empty CSS and add what you need to get the job done. Learn the CSS you need. You will not be productive asking us every time you have a CSS "problem".